Navigation Rail in Flutter
I am developing a dashboard with flutter web. I have this side menu where i am changing pages like a normal dashboard. Here's the design that i want to copy:

but somehow navigation rail is not letting me do many things. One is putting on labels in Navigation destination. I tried icon: Icon(null) but it is still taking the space.. second problem is top logo.. I want it to be left aligned not centered.
